# Writing very simple webserver in C - browser hangs

Tags: c, http, networking, webserver, request

Hello i am trying to write a very simple webserver. It will respond same simple web page to any request. Here is fragment of code:

```
while(1) {

  if ((newFd = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddr, &sockAddrSize)) == ERROR) {
      printf("error accept\n");
      close(s);
      return;
   }

  pid = fork();

  if(pid == 0) {
      handle_request(newFd);
      close(newFd);
      return;
  }
}
```

And the handle requset function is:

```
void handle_request(int newFd) {

  int readBytes;
  int sendBytes;
  readBytes = recv(newFd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0);

  sendBytes = send(newFd, page, strlen(page), 0);
  printf("I have send %d B out of %d B\n", sendBytes, strlen(page));
}
```

Where page is simple global variable:

```
char *page = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello</h1>\r\n";
```

What happens is, that browser is waiting (seems like receiving data, the circle in the tab is rotating) and displays nothing (tried Firefox and Chromium). Only after i kill the main process (with the accept()) it will display the page.

I dont know where could be problem, I think I am doing it right. I for new process, send the response and close the descriptor returned by accept and close the child.

Comment: Maybe BUFFSIZE is too small and the browser still tries to send the request data (before starting to read the response)?

Comment: BUFFSIZE is 1000, request header from browser has about 250 bytes. The program will print that it send 57 out of 57 Bytes in response.

Comment: I think you should close new file descriptor in parent.

Comment: @zch But how to know that the child already completed the request? i cannot close it immediatelly...

Comment: You can. It will be active as long as there is any process that uses it. At least, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Anyone writing this up as an answer so that I can upvote and user561838 can accept?

Comment: char *page = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-length：14\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello</h1>";

Comment: you can try add Content-length field in http protocal

Answer (score 0):

The browser is "hung" because it is still waiting for data. It has two ways of knowing that there will be no more data. Either via a header stating the length of the content (`content-length`) or by the server closing the socket indicating that the server has finished sending.

There are two main issues in your code, you aren't closing the socket both in the main process and in the forked process but you just return, I suspect that you're running this in the main process where it will not matter but in general it is good practice to call exit() in forked children. If you don't they will keep running and can lead to some nasty and hard to find bugs. If you don't close `newFd` in the while-loop you will eventually run out of socket descriptors and your server will not be able to accept new requests.